# Master theorem for subproblems of different sizes

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

The [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form)'s generic form mentions that:

> it is assumed that all subproblems are essentially the same size

The [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) is applied when:

> the sub-problems have substantially different sizes

But what are the criteria for **substantially** different? For example I have a recurrence relation like:

```
T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + cn 
(c is some constant)
```

Can I still use the master theorem to solve this relation  (for instance approximating it as `T(n) = 2T(3n/4) + cn`)? Or, in other words, are these subproblem sizes "essentially the same" or are they already "substantially different"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `c` is some constant, you have: `T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + O(n)`

Solving this with the Akra-Bazzi method gives `O(n^2)`

Solving it by assuming `T(n) = 2T(3n/4) + O(n)` gives `O(n^2.4094)` (exp. rounded to 4 dp)

So just by trying it out, you can confirm that they are already substantially different.

Comment: Thanks. Then I assume insubstantially different is when I have something like `T(n) = T(n/2 - 1) + T(n/2 + 1) + cn` i.e. when the parts are not exact but differ only by some constant.